# Changing image in Flask template through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, templates, dom, flask

So I have a flask app that has only one template (html file). The html file is changed through a javascript file. It changes the DOM through jquery and flask doesnt have a problem with this. However, when I'm changing a img tag it has trouble. 
This is my javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    mainPage = $("#mainPage");
    setMainPage();
});

function setMainPage(){
    mainPage.html('<div><a href= "#"><img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/facebook.png') }}" alt="icon" class="socialBtns"></a></div>');
}
```

this returns the error: "missing ) after argument list" and the error happens on the line number where I set mainPage.html(). So i thought it was the ' quotes that were causing the problem. so I escaped them using the backslash like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    mainPage = $("#mainPage");
    setMainPage();
});

function setMainPage(){
    mainPage.html('<div><a href= "#"><img src="{{ url_for(\'static\',filename=\'images/facebook.png\') }}" alt="icon" class="socialBtns"></a></div>');
}
```

But when i do that all the text loads in just fine but the image spits out an error "http://127.0.0.1:5000/%7B%7B%20url_for('static',filename='images/facebook.png')%20%7D%7D 404 (NOT FOUND)"

So i tried setting this src url ({{ url_for(\'static\',filename=\'images/facebook.png\') }}) inside the html template to see if maybe i had a typo, and i don't. When it's loaded into the html template the image loads just fine. But for some reason when  i try to change the DOM from my JS file it doesn't want to work. I've looked everywhere for a similar problem. but nobody seems to have this same issue. I even saw a blog post of someone changing the dom through ajax the exact same way and it worked fine. Please help.

Comment: The `{{ }}` blocks are evaluated on server-side, there is no way to use `url_for` with javascript on client-side in DOM manipulations.

Comment: yeah, i ended up using a complete route instead so: "static/images/facebook.png"